# contribution to change logo in all pages nuxeo

Tags: interface, customization, nuxeo

I want to change my nuxeo application logo. I've read how to change it for login page and it's working , but now i want to change logo for all my page and i can't find any tutorial of how to do this.
Here is what i've tried so far:

```
    <component name="org.nuxeo.sample.loginPage">
  <extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.ui.web.auth.service.PluggableAuthenticationService" point="loginScreen">
    <loginScreenConfig>
      <disableBackgroundSizeCover>false</disableBackgroundSizeCover>
      <headerStyle></headerStyle>
      <footerStyle></footerStyle>
     <loginBoxWidth>400px</loginBoxWidth>
      <logoUrl>${org.nuxeo.ecm.contextPath}/img/logo12.png</logoUrl>
      <logoAlt>MyCompany</logoAlt>
      <logoWidth>113</logoWidth>
      <logoHeight>20</logoHeight>
       <newsIframeUrl>https://www.nuxeo.com/embedded/dm-login</newsIframeUrl>
    </loginScreenConfig>
  </extension>
</component>
```

Comment: Which Nuxeo version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You got it for the login screen. For the other pages, give a look at the [org.nuxeo.theme.styling.service](http://explorer.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/site/distribution/Nuxeo%20Platform-7.2/viewComponent/org.nuxeo.theme.styling.service) component and its [flavors](http://explorer.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/site/distribution/Nuxeo%20Platform-7.2/viewExtensionPoint/org.nuxeo.theme.styling.service--flavors) extension point.

You will need such an XML contribution:

```
<extension target="org.nuxeo.theme.styling.service" point="flavors">
  <flavor name="myCompanyFlavor" extends="default">
    <logo>
      <path>/img/logo12.png</path>
      <previewPath>/img/logo12.png</previewPath>
      <width></width>
      <height></height>
      <title>MyCompany</title>
    </logo>
  </flavor>
</extension>
```

Comment: thank you, i tried this but i can't get to work , can you give me more details i mean what should I add in the other files , or just give me some tutorial ?

Comment: The easier is to use Nuxeo Studio and look at the generated extension point. You can also try with Nuxeo IDE for Eclipse.

Comment: Actually, i'm using Nuxeo IDE for Eclipse

Comment: Nice. Which Nuxeo version do you use? Don't you have some related logs? If the first contribution works, the one I provided should work too...

Comment: I'm using version 6, in order to change login page logo , i'va created a login-contrib.xml and add it in manifest.mf , but i don't know how to add the one you gave to me , can you list all the steps. Thank you for your help